# Customization: Removing Line Color

Tags: visual-studio-code

Do you guys know how to remove line color in vscode? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the blue vertical  line next to lines 27-30?

Comment: @Mark just the thin line.

Comment: Those are indent guides.    "editor.renderIndentGuides": false;  will get rid of them.

Comment: @Mark Thank You!